# Change PyCharm auto indent of multi-line list

Tags: pycharm

I want multi-line lists to be formatted as:

```
long_list = [
    6,
    8,
]
```

Instead, PyCharm wants to indent this as:

```
long_list = [
  6,
  8,
  ]
```

which I hate! I have indent set to two spaces and continuation indent set to four spaces. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Select the list,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or got to `Code > Auto-indent lines`. PyCharm will indent the code.

Answer (score 0):

In settings, you can go to `Editor > Code style > Python > Wrapping and Braces` and uncheck `Hang closing brackets`. Then, auto indent should format the braces as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Smart keys` , you should go to `Editor > General > Smart Keys`, in the `Enter` tab, make sure you check `Smart indent`